# Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using GraphQL along with NodeJs and Mongoose (I guess GraphQL won't matter here)

When I run my Query, **I am getting a message saying cannot read property `save` of undefined.**

```
      resolve (parent, args) {
        let books
        book.find(
            {
            name: args.name
            }, function (error, result){
                console.log(result.length)
                if (result.length == 0) { 

                    console.log(args.name)
                    books = new book({
                        name: args.name, 
                        genre: args.genre,
                        authorName: args.authorName
                    })    
                    Author.find(
                        {
                        name: args.authorName
                        },
                        function (err, results) {
                            if (results.length == 0) {
                                let author = new Author({ 
                                    name: args.authorName
                                })
                            author.save()
                        }
                        });
                }
            })
                return books.save()
        }
```

This is my code, above notice the two console.log. The first console.log shows the length to be zero and the second console.log does have a value in it

Also, Author and book is a mongoose schema which I am importing

```
const Author = require("../models/author.js")
const book = require("../models/book.js")
```

I declared `let books` just below the `resolve (parent, args) {` for the sake of scope.

**Question:** Now, I don't have much of experience with JS so can someone help me and share what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: `.find` method is asynchronous, you call `.save` before the query has executed

Comment: @FrankerZ the callback is executed after he has called `.save`

Comment: Can you show us the order of your logs in console? as i think you will be getting undefined error then the results value is getting logged... keep the books.save in same asynchronous call as in authors case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that book.find function is async. This means that the line containing `return books.save()` is going to be executed before the callback of the book.find function does. You can move the call to book save inside the callback after you set the books variable.